# Is there any npm package to read Excel file which is in .xlsm format?

Tags: node.js, excel, npm, xlsm, vba

I am having a base template which is in the .xslm format and I want to read this file and preserve all those VBA and macros in it

I tried using npm's [xslx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) package it preserves the VBA and macros but I am loosing all data validations and styles.I want a package that support writing .xlsm format without losing the VBA and macros.

Any other packages will do this job?

Comment: People who are down voting it , realize it there is no npm package that supports this functionality. If you have any answer ,let me know

Answer (score 0):

You could try [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel).
Here's an example, from their npm page:

```
var parseXlsx = require('excel');

parseXlsx('Spreadsheet.xlsx', function(err, data) {
  if(err) throw err;
    // data is an array of arrays
});
```

[Source](https://github.com/trevordixon/excel.js).

There's also [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssm-xlsx). Which supports more formats.

The GitHub page for the project seems to be gone, however.

As well as [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel-parser).
Example:

```
var excelParser = require('excel-parser');
excelParser.worksheets({
  inFile: 'my_file.in'
}, function(err, worksheets){
  if(err) console.error(err);
  console.log(worksheets);
});
```

[Source](https://github.com/leftshifters/excel-parser).

Comment: The problem with these packages is they don't support writing .xslm excel files. They might read but they can't support write. I need to do some data manipulation and write the file in .xlsm format without losing any of the VBA and macro.

Comment: @JaspherJ https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssm-xlsx claims to support that format I believe.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but they don't support writing .xlsm file format.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry about that. You should probably update your question to include reading and writing to the file. As for the question, I think you'll have to end up making your own writer. I can't find any online that support it.

Comment: I guess so. That's why I planned to shift the platform to C# Net.